# как создать конструктор используя lombok

Tags: java, lombok

допустим есть класс:

```
class Student{
int Id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
int age;}
```

1. Я хочу создать конструктор c аргументами: lastName, firstName, age. Как это сделать используя lombok? 
   `@RequiredArgsConstructor`создаст конструктор, используя все свойства класса.
2. Как мне, используя lombok создать второй конструктор с аргументами firstName и age?

Comment: @AllArgsConstructor

Comment: а для чего нужны эти несколько конструкторов? может воспользоваться @Builder на классом(можно и над конструктором), код будет `Student s = Strudent.builder().firstName("alex").lastName("Alex2").build();`, можно комбинировать нужные параметры как хочется.

Answer (score 1):

Просто объявите нужные вам поля (firstName и age) как final и добавьте на класс аннотацию @RequiredArgsConstructor.

Если вы хотите и такой конструктор (с параметрами firstName и age), и ещё с тремя параметрами - проще тот, который с тремя, написать самому, благо в IDE такая операция, как генерация конструктора, занимает пару секунд.

Comment: т.е. получается, что с помощью lombook я могу объявить только один конструктор?
А если будет 7 полей у класса, и конструкторов 5, тогда нет смысла один прятать, а 4 дописывать руками

Comment: ты можешь ломбоком создать конструктор по-умолчанию (@NoArgsConstructor),  со всеми аргументами (@AllArgsConstructor) и с аргументами для инициализации только final полей.   Если тебе нужно что-то еще, пиши сам конструкторы